# Loading data from csv to pandas dataframe gives NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using the following code to read a csv file into pandas but when I move it into a data frame, I am only getting Nans. I need to put it into dataframe to work on loading it into SQL Server.
I am using the following code to load the data into csv file:

```
for file in z.namelist():
    df1=pd.read_csv(z.open(file),sep='\t',skiprows=[1,2])
print(df1)
```

This gives me the intended results:
[image]
But when I try to put the data into a dataframe, I am getting only NaNs. This is the code that I am using to load the data into data frame after the step above.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['ResponseID','ResponseSet','IPAddress','StartDate','EndDate',
        'RecipientLastName','RecipientFirstName','RecipientEmail','ExternalDataReference','Finished',
        'Status','EmbeddedData','License Type','Organization','Reference ID','Q16','Q3#1_1_1_TEXT',
        'Q3#1_1_2_TEXT','Q3#1_1_3_TEXT','Q3#1_2_1_TEXT','Q3#1_2_3_TEXT','Q3#1_3_1_TEXT','Q3#1_3_2_TEXT',
        'Q3#1_3_3_TEXT','Q3#1_4_1_TEXT','Q3#1_4_2_TEXT','Q3#1_4_3_TEXT','Q3#1_5_1_TEXT','Q3#1_5_2_TEXT',
        'Q3#1_5_3_TEXT','Q3#1_6_1_TEXT','Q3#1_6_2_TEXT','Q3#1_6_3_TEXT','Q4#1_5_1_TEXT','Q18','Q19#1_1_1_TEXT',
        'Q19#1_2_1_TEXT','Q19#1_3_1_TEXT','Q19#1_4_1_TEXT','Q19#1_6_1_TEXT','Q14#1_4_1_TEXT','Q14#1_5_1_TEXT',
        'Q14#1_8_1_TEXT','Q20','Q29','Q21','Q22','Q23','Q24','LocationLatitude','LocationLongitude','LocationAccuracy'])
    
print(df1)
```

I am getting only NaNs on for this.
[image]

What should I do to get the data from csv into my data frame and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `df1` is already dataframe. You may need to figure out the separator of your csv at first.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, I am trying to get my data to be like the 2nd screeshot. So that when I refer df1['ResponseID'], I get all the data in ResponseID and so on.

Comment: In the result of `df1=pd.read_csv(z.open(file),sep='\t',skiprows=[1,2])`, your separator seems to be `,` rather than `\t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using "," as a separator for my read_csv.

```
df1=pd.read_csv(z.open(file),sep=',',skiprows=[1,2])
```

I got rid of the NaNs by using the following:

```
df1 = df1.replace({np.nan: None})
```